# Laravel/Stripe - How do I reconcile between logging out and syncing my User model's details for Stripe?

Tags: php, laravel

## Situation

I have a fairly standard `User` model with the `Billable` trait. I'm using Stripe in this project, and User represents my stripe customers.

Per laravel docs, I've got the following code in the User model:

```php
protected static function booted() {
    static::updated(queueable(function ($user) { $user->syncStripeCustomerDetails(); }));
}
```

This is my logout code in `LoginController@logout`:

```php
public function logout() {
   auth()->logout();
   return redirect("/login");
}
```

## What's happening

Whenever I navigate to the `/logout` route, I get this error:

> Stripe\Exception\InvalidArgumentException.
> The resource ID cannot be null or whitespace.

I'm assuming there's some conflict between the code that expects to sync the `User` object with `Stripe`...

If I refresh the page, all seems to work fine.

## Expected behaviour

User syncs to Stripe customer. System logs user out and navigates to `/login` without any error.

Any pointers? Thanks in advance.

Comment: show us your syncStripeCustomerDetails()

Comment: Hey. It's not one of my functions. It's in the laravel docs. Guessing it's part of the laravel/stripe package. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing

Comment: sorry, I didnt know because I never used that package, but I think you can fix that issue by handle `InvalidArgumentException` in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`